# subpanel tied to main thru 50 amp double. One 20 amp outside receptacle. Can I put another 20 amp on the subpanel?

Tags: electrical

hot tub gone but subpanel still being fed from main that has a 50 amp double. Can I run two 20 amp outdoor receptacles from that 50 amp subpanel?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of said subpanel?  What are you trying to power with these receptacles, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

If the subpanel was installed correctly You can run the two twenty amp circuits. They will have to be GFCI protected.

Comment: Many hot tub panels are wired for 240V only...

Comment: So if the panel is 4 wire connected it would be ok. Since there is 1 outlet it should be ok or the existing outlet is not code compliant.